# Why color-pickers are disabled in context menu in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, contextmenu, color-picker

I'm new to SwiftUI, can you help me?
Why color pickers are disabled in context menu of Rectangle struct?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZz4c.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGpPV.png)

I tried to search answer in documentation, but I hadn't found anything about it.

Comment: Probably becuase they would both be presenting in the same spot.I’m the hierarchy

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.